# How to modify ListView on ICS so it looks like an about activity in google+ app?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-plus

I want to do a similar activity in my app. I know how to modify the `Adapter` class, but in my opinion it's difficult for this situation. Is there more simple way to do a similar activity? Image is here:

[image]

Comment: For these types of screens that are extremely dynamic, it seems like programatically adding each section to a ScrollView may be easier than creating a complex ArrayAdapter implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is not a `ListView`, It is just a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation inside `ScrollView`. Avoid using `ListView` if you have few static views.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the list adapter of this activity , try [CWAC Merge Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) , I use that implement a similar activity.

And if you mean the Tab Adapter , use [ActionbarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) with ViewPager in android-support-v4 , I have done that too.

They all have demos , try them out.